# Selenium Click with actions vs click without actions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was testing a scraper and I noticed that when using:

```
WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id*='tabOne']"));
tab.click();
```

I receive this message constantly:

```
1536868112230   Marionette  DEBUG   [6442450945] Canceled page load listener because no navigation has been detected
```

However when I use this instead:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id*='tabOne']"));
builder.click(tab).perform();
```

I don't receive a message every time I sift through the tabs or click on new links.

Am I receiving this message because I am not emulating the user behavior thus I get thrown this message because it was waiting for a user click on the tab? And since I am scraping and not testing, is it better to just use the former instead of the latter since I don't need to interact with the GUI anyways?

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful... are you waiting for a page load in your first sample?

Comment: Also, why is the `WebElement` object called `tab` but then `tabs` when invoked?

Comment: Sure! So actually no I am not waiting for a page load. I have some Thread.sleeps around the scraper to ensure that everything loads but yeah, when using both methods in my scraper, I get identical data. The tab and tabs was a mistake, I will correct that now! I was just showing a snippet but basically whenever I clicked on new links, new modal-content boxes would pop up where I would click the tabs and information that was collapsed would be expanded. But every action I made, clicking on the link, clicking on new tabs, exiting the modal box, was causing that message. Hope this made sense!

Comment: Share html in text format

Comment: What webdriver are you using? What browser is the test running on?